# What is the max level a dwarf can be?

Tags: a-game-of-dwarves

Is there a max level that a dwarf can get to?

Was playing a level (cant remember its name, was the one with the green mage) and saw the mage was like 86 (or there about), which got me wondering, can I can a dwarf to that level as well, or is it capped somewhere?